# how to solve No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' while creating new endpoints with terraform cloudfront and django

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have created an application using django react, terrafor, aws cloudfront and nginx

all my endpoints that i have been working on for weeks work well.

Now i have tried to add new endpoints when i try to make a request from the front end, i get the following errors:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https: //api.foo.com/new-url-enpoints/' from origin 'https: //www.foo.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
main.a1abe898.chunk.js:1 Page error:  Error: Network Error
    at e.exports (1.v3s1s213.chunk.js:1:21345)
    at XMLHttpRequest.p.onerror (1.v3s1s213.chunk.js:1:63362)
1.v3s1s213.chunk.js:1          POST https: //api.foo.com/new-url-enpoints/ net::ERR_FAILED 500
```

## S3 bucket

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "my_bucket" {
  bucket        = "some-bucket"
  ...

  cors_rule {
    allowed_headers = [
      "Accept",
      "Accept-Encoding",
      "Authorization",
      "Content-Type",
      "Dnt",
      "Origin",
      "User-Agent",
      "X-Csrftoken",
      "X-Requested-With",
    ]
    allowed_methods = ["PUT", "POST", "GET", "DELETE", "HEAD"]
    allowed_origins = ["https: //www.foo.com"] # i have created the space to be able to post this question on stackoverflow
    expose_headers  = ["Etag"]
    max_age_seconds = 3000
  }
```

## FRONTEND

```
locals {
  s3_origin_id = "www.foo.com"
}

resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "front_end_cloudfront" {
  origin {
    domain_name = aws_s3_bucket.my_bucket.bucket_regional_domain_name
    origin_id   = local.s3_origin_id

    s3_origin_config {
      origin_access_identity = "${aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity.s3_oai.cloudfront_access_identity_path}"
    }
  }

  enabled             = true
  is_ipv6_enabled     = true
  default_root_object = "index.html"

  aliases = ["www.foo.com"]

  custom_error_response {
    error_caching_min_ttl = 500
    error_code            = 403
    response_code         = 403
    response_page_path    = "/index.html"
  }

  default_cache_behavior {
    allowed_methods  = ["GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS", "PATCH", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"]
    cached_methods   = ["GET", "HEAD"]
    target_origin_id = local.s3_origin_id

    forwarded_values {
      query_string = false

      cookies {
        forward = "none"
      }
    }

    viewer_protocol_policy = "redirect-to-https"
    min_ttl                = 0
    default_ttl            = 0
    max_ttl                = 0
  }

  # cache behavior with precedence 0
  ordered_cache_behavior {
    path_pattern     = "/content/immutable/*"
    allowed_methods  = ["GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS", "PATCH", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"]
    cached_methods   = ["GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"]
    target_origin_id = local.s3_origin_id

    forwarded_values {
      query_string = false
      headers      = ["Origin"]

      cookies {
        forward = "none"
      }
    }

    min_ttl                = 0
    default_ttl            = 0
    max_ttl                = 0
    compress               = true
    viewer_protocol_policy = "redirect-to-https"
  }

  # cache behavior with precedence 1
  ordered_cache_behavior {
    path_pattern     = "/content/*"
    allowed_methods  = ["GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS", "PATCH", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"]
    cached_methods   = ["GET", "HEAD"]
    target_origin_id = local.s3_origin_id

    forwarded_values {
      query_string = false

      cookies {
        forward = "none"
      }
    }

    min_ttl                = 0
    default_ttl            = 0
    max_ttl                = 0
    compress               = true
    viewer_protocol_policy = "redirect-to-https"
  }

  ...
}
```

## BACKEND

```
locals {
  lb_origin_id = "api.foo.com"
}

resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "backend_cloudfront" {
  origin {
    domain_name = aws_lb.backend_lb.dns_name
    origin_id   = local.lb_origin_id

    custom_origin_config {
      http_port  = 80
      https_port = 443
      origin_protocol_policy = "http-only"
      origin_ssl_protocols = ["TLSv1.2"]
    }
  }

  enabled             = true
  is_ipv6_enabled     = true

  aliases = ["api.foo.com"]

  default_cache_behavior {
    allowed_methods  = ["GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS", "PATCH", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"]
    cached_methods   = ["GET", "HEAD"]
    target_origin_id = local.lb_origin_id

    forwarded_values {
      query_string            = true
      headers                 = ["*"]
      query_string_cache_keys = []

      cookies {
        forward = "none"
      }
    }

    viewer_protocol_policy = "redirect-to-https"
    min_ttl                = 0
    default_ttl            = 0
    max_ttl                = 0
  }

  # cache behavior with precedence 0
  ordered_cache_behavior {
    path_pattern     = "/api/*"
    allowed_methods  = ["GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS", "PATCH", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"]
    cached_methods   = ["GET", "HEAD"]
    target_origin_id = local.lb_origin_id

    forwarded_values {
      query_string            = true
      headers                 = ["*"]
      query_string_cache_keys = []

      cookies {
        forward = "none"
      }
    }

    min_ttl                = 0
    default_ttl            = 0
    max_ttl                = 0
    compress               = true
    viewer_protocol_policy = "redirect-to-https"
  }

  ...
}
```

## nginx

```
server {

        listen 80;
        server_name SECRET;

        location / {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'h ttps://www.foo.com' always; # space created on purpose
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,HEAD' always;
                add_header 'X-XSS-Protection' '1; mode=block' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Content-Type,Accept,Origin,User-Agent,DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,X-Requested-With,Keep-Alive,X-CsrfToken' always;
                ...
        }
        ....
}
```

this configuration keep failing , only for the new endpoints created, i think it should be related to the cache with cloudfront but i am not sure how to fix

any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Check if you have set up the listeners properly for your load balancer.

Answer (score 0):

I think below should solve your issue, if the error is indeed due to cloudfront config. The CloudFront distribution config should forward the headers that are required by your origin. If your origin is an S3 bucket, then configure your distribution to forward the following headers to Amazon S3:

- Access-Control-Request-Headers
- Access-Control-Request-Method
- Origin

### Steps to do this change:

1. Open your distribution from the CloudFront console.
2. Choose the Behaviors tab.
3. Choose Create Behavior. Or, select an existing behavior, and then choose Edit.
4. Under Cache key and origin requests, choose Cache policy and origin request policy. Then, for Origin request policy, choose either CORS-S3Origin or CORS-CustomOrigin from the dropdown list.
5. Choose Save Changes.

Src: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/no-access-control-allow-origin-error/

Comment: thanks for the feedback i actually already made the changes before your post `headers      = ["Origin", "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers"]` in `forwarded_values` of `aws_cloudfront_distribution` for the front end or s3....now the only error i see on the network tab is `Request failed with status code 500` while nginx (the webserver)is not down, neither is django...i have not idea what to do, i have tried everything....the whole day

Comment: Error 500 means you app code has an exception. Check nginx logs.

Comment: believe me what i am facing is a very weird situation because i checked nginx and there is nothing there in the logs. im wondering how it is possible because all the previous endpoints work fine but i open the page with the new endoint i see the 500 message in the network tab